# C# How can I kill a process with .exe changing name, unnamed window and cannot use PID because I need to use something that does not change?

Tags: c#, process, filenames, kill-process

For learning purposes and mere curiosity I have been trying somehow to kill a process with the characteristics explained above in the title:

**1. The name of the file changes every time it is downloaded.**

**2. Window without a name.**

**(I can't use PID because I need something that doesn't change to make it automatic)**

**(The exe name always start with DaxSS-**

Example names:

DaxSS-TSFGR

DaxSS-RFDUC

DaxSS-GFFRS

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does the process have a user interface of some kind that you could search to find a particular type of control or a pattern of controls with a parent/child relationship?  Otherwise you'd probably have to detect the file being downloaded somehow.  Does it always get downloaded to the same folder?  If so, you could maybe use FileSystemWatcher?  Is the SIZE of the file always the size?   Iterate over all processes and use Process.MainModule.FileName?  Etc...

Comment: The downloaded exe name always start with DaxSS-

Comment: It has a logo on the interface, also text "Welcome to dax" and a button with a text: "Go"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The downloaded exe name always start with DaxSS

That's your ticket right there!

```
string start = "DaxSS".ToUpper();
Process P = Process.GetProcesses().Where((p) => p.ProcessName.ToUpper().StartsWith(start)).FirstOrDefault();            
if (P != null)
{
    P.Kill();
}
```